# Error: Unable to access jarfile project-0.0.1.jar in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Spring boot Project which I compile and convert to Docker image. But after deployment using helm chart I get error in Kubernetes:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl logs project-7665465d69-d6gms
Error: Unable to access jarfile project-0.0.1.jar
```

Project Docker file:

```
# Use a Java runtime as the base image
FROM openjdk:17-slim-buster

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the built JAR file into the container
COPY build/libs/*.jar /app/

# Expose the default port for the app
EXPOSE 8888

# Start the app when the container launches
CMD ["java", "-jar", "project-0.0.1.jar"]
```

Still I can't find a solution. Output after Jenkins job compilation:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t project:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  244.2MB

Step 1/5 : FROM openjdk:17-slim-buster
 ---> b97928de0b87
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f78fc1d3075d
Step 3/5 : COPY build/libs/*.jar /app/
 ---> 51871362ec3e
Step 4/5 : EXPOSE 8888
 ---> Running in b292313b5f81
Removing intermediate container b292313b5f81
 ---> c941ec4f694a
Step 5/5 : CMD ["java", "-jar", "project-0.0.1.jar"]
 ---> Running in 8f52d424b589
Removing intermediate container 8f52d424b589
 ---> 612da66aa7b4
Successfully built 612da66aa7b4
Successfully tagged project:latest
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are copying the jar and you might not know the name of it, and you are trying to run `project-0.0.1.jar` which might be different in name with the one you are copying, what you can do is update your Dockerfile to

```
# Use a Java runtime as the base image
FROM openjdk:17-slim-buster

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the built JAR file into the container
COPY build/libs/*.jar /app/project-0.0.1.jar

# Expose the default port for the app
EXPOSE 8888

# Start the app when the container launches
CMD ["java", "-jar", "project-0.0.1.jar"]
```

updated the COPY line so that after copying, its name should be `project-0.0.1.jar`

Comment: I get `Step 3/5 : COPY build/libs/*.jar /app/project-0.0.1.jar
When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /`

Comment: Can you propose what debug messages I can add in order to verify the build into Docker file?

Comment: which means there are multiple jar files in the folder `build/libs/` otherwise it works fine, also where is your build command? have you removed it for the question or it is like this?
this is my working example: https://github.com/kahootali/SpringJavaMonitoringApp/blob/main/Dockerfile

Comment: I use gradle. I build it using Jenkins job: `./gradlew clean build --no-daemon` command. This produces into build/libs 2 files: `project-0.0.1.jar` and `project-0.0.1-plain.jar`. After that the command `docker build -t project:latest .` is used to compile the project into Docker image.

Comment: then that is why it is saying that "When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory" because it is trying to copy 2 jars, so instead you can use "COPY build/libs/project-0.0.1.jar /app/" in your Dockerfile

Comment: I get file not found during docker build  step.

Comment: then that means "project-0.0.1.jar" isn't there in your "build/libs/" folder, so you need to check that step which builds it, the gradle command in your Jenkins job

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254484/discussion-between-ali-kahoot-and-peter-penzov).

Comment: The solution was - `settings.gradle` file was missing.